# Selecting rows from DataTables fails unless search UI is visible

Tags: datatables

I want to hide the search user interface, but when I do so, the api based row selection fails. Works fine if searching is enabled. When I read the docs, I thought I was disabling the UI, but it is obviously the search feature instead.

I actually have DataTables for schools and school districts, and want to only display the schools from a specific district when used clicks on district table to select a district. User can also select a school from the school table

```js
// DataTable Initialization for school table
dTable = $tblSchools.DataTable({
select: {
    style: 'single',
    items: 'row',
},
paging: false,
searching: true, // selecting rows only works when enabled - makes sense
info: false,
destroy: true
});

// snippet from event handler on 'select' event of district table
var dTable = $tblSchools.DataTable();
var district = '123'; // real code messier, console.log(district) shows it works

// district number is always column 1
// the next line is what fails (silently, no exception)
dTable.column(1).search(district, false, false).draw();
```

Environment, jQuery 1.9.1, DataTables 1.10.12, select plugin 1.2.0

Is there some setting I have overlooked to hide the search UI without disabling the search function entirely.

If I have to do this a different way, would appreciated being pointed to a simple equivalent way that allows me to hide the DataTables search UI, but show schools based on district.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some setting I have overlooked to hide the search UI without
>   disabling the search function entirely

Yes. Remove the `f` flag from the [**`dom`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) defaults :

```js
dTable = $tblSchools.DataTable({
  dom: 'lrtip',
  ...
})
```

Now the filter input / "search UI" is removed but you can still perform searches by code.